# Blazor webassembly, state management. Refresh child components

Tags: state-management, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

I am selecting items from the list, and displaying their different content.
It is working correctly with this code:

```
public class ItemState
{
    public Item CurrentItem { get; set; }
    public event Action OnItemSelected;
    public void SetItemValue(Item item)
    {
        CurrentItem = item;
        NotifyStateChanged();
    }

    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnItemSelected?.Invoke();
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    ItemState.OnItemSelected += StateHasChanged;
}
```

In the Item component I am using other components and passing as parameter Item itself, like:
`<ItemHistory ItemModel="@Item"/>`
But ItemHIstory component is not refreshing, when selecting different items.
There is always shown first selected item's history.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to use StateContainer, so properties then are are accessible for all components.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly